# Create non repeated pairs between results and manufactures, why results are not displayed in `#ModelBranchManufacturer`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I've this HTML code:

```
<fieldset class="rpni-border">
    <legend class="rpni-border">Model</legend>
    <table id="contenedorModelos" style="" class="table table-condensed">
        <tbody id="modeloBody">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" value="1" id="selModelo1" name="selModelos">
                </td>
                <td>Harum.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" value="4" id="selModelo4" name="selModelos">
                </td>
                <td>Pariatur ut.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" value="6" id="selModelo6" name="selModelos">
                </td>
                <td>Tempore animi.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" value="8" id="selModelo8" name="selModelos">
                </td>
                <td>Voluptatem.</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="rpni-border">
    <legend class="rpni-border">Branch</legend>
    <table id="contenedorMarcas" style="" class="table table-condensed">
        <tbody id="marcaBody">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" value="3" id="selMarca3" name="selMarcas">
                </td>
                <td>Ea in sequi.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" value="7" id="selMarca7" name="selMarcas">
                </td>
                <td>Exercitationem.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" value="11" id="selMarca11" name="selMarcas">
                </td>
                <td>Sit alias sit.</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="rpni-border">
    <legend class="rpni-border">Manufacturer</legend>
    <table id="contenedorFabricante" style="" class="table table-condensed">
        <tbody id="fabricanteBody">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="3">
                </td>
                <td>Ea in sequi.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="7">
                </td>
                <td>Exercitationem.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="11">
                </td>
                <td>Sit alias sit.</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</fieldset>
<button id="create" type="button">Create</button>
<div id="ModelBranch"></div>
<button id="createM" type="button">Join Model-Branch with Manufacturer</button>
<div id="ModelBranchManufacturer"></div>
```

And then there is this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function modelBranchManufacturerObject(config) {
        var instance = this;

        // initialize class vars
        instance.modelKey = config.modelKey;
        instance.branchKey = config.branchKey;
        instance.manufacturerKeyCollection = [];

        instance.globalKey;

        // globalKey = modelKey + branchKey
        instance.getGlobalKey = function () {
            if (!instance.globalKey) {
                instance.globalKey = instance.modelKey + '-' + instance.branchKey;
            }

            return instance.globalKey;
        }

        instance.addManufacturerKeyCollection = function (manufacturerArray) {
            instance.manufacturerKeyCollection = manufacturerArray;
        }
    }

    var modelBranchManufacturerCollection = {};

    function addNewRelationModelBranch(modelKey, branchKey) {
        var tempModelBranchManufacturerObjectInstance = new modelBranchManufacturerObject({
            modelKey: modelKey,
            branchKey: branchKey
        });

        var globalKey = tempModelBranchManufacturerObjectInstance.getGlobalKey();

        if (!modelBranchManufacturerCollection[globalKey]) {
            modelBranchManufacturerCollection[globalKey] = tempModelBranchManufacturerObjectInstance;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

        return tempModelBranchManufacturerObjectInstance;
    }

    function addNewRelationModelBranchManufacturer(globalKey, manufacturerArray) {
        if (modelBranchManufacturerCollection[globalKey]) {
            modelBranchManufacturerCollection[globalKey].manufacturerKeyCollection = manufacturerArray;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

        return modelBranchManufacturerCollection;
    }

    var html = '<table><tbody id="branchModel"></tbody></table>';
    $("#ModelBranch").html(html);

    $("#create").on("click", function () {
        var currModel = $("#modeloBody").find("input[type='radio']:checked").val(),
            currBranch = $("#marcaBody").find("input[type='radio']:checked").val(),
            ModelBranchObject, tr;

        if (currModel && currBranch) {
            ModelBranchObject = addNewRelationModelBranch(currModel, currBranch);

            if (ModelBranchObject) {
                tr = '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" value="' + ModelBranchObject.globalKey + '" /></td>';
                tr += '<td>' + ModelBranchObject.modelKey + '-' + ModelBranchObject.branchKey + '</td></tr>';

                $("#branchModel").append(tr);
            }
        }
    });

    var htmlManufacturer = '<table><tbody id="branchModelManufacturer"></tbody></table>';
    $("#ModelBranchManufacturer").html(htmlManufacturer);

    $("#createM").on("click", function () {
        var checkedModelBranch = $("#branchModelManufacturer").find("input[type='checkbox']:checked"),
            checkedManufacturers = $("#fabricanteBody").find("input[type='checkbox']:checked"),
            manufacturerColl = [],
            trManufacturer,
            ModelBranchManufacturerObject;


        for (var j = 0; j < checkedManufacturers.length; j++) {
            manufacturerColl.push(checkedManufacturers[j].value);
        }

        console.log(manufacturerColl);

        for (var i = 0; i < checkedModelBranch.length; i++) {
            ModelBranchManufacturerObject = addNewRelationModelBranchManufacturer(checkedModelBranch[i].value, manufacturerColl);
            console.log(ModelBranchManufacturerObject);
            if (ModelBranchManufacturerObject) {
                trManufacturer = '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" value="' + ModelBranchManufacturerObject.globalKey + '" /></td>';
                trManufacturer += '<td>' + ModelBranchObject.modelKey + '-' + ModelBranchObject.branchKey;

                for (var k = 0; k < ModelBranchObject.manufacturerKeyCollection.length; k++) {
                    trManufacturer += ModelBranchObject.manufacturerKeyCollection[k] + '<br/>';
                }

                trManufacturer += '</td></tr>';

                $("#branchModelManufacturer").append(trManufacturer);
            }

            console.log(trManufacturer);
        }

    });
});
```

What this code does is allow to pick a model and a branch and create a non repeated pairs between them and also show the results on `#modelBranch` div. Also allow, I think if I'm not doing something wrong, to pick one|many choices from the results in the previous step (those on `#modelBranch`) and one|many Manufacturers and again create a non repeated pairs between them but in this case I can not show the results on `#ModelBranchManufacturer` as I should do so something is not working on my code and I was not able to find where I'm failing so certainly I need some help or advice from you. For clear a bit how the process is take a look at the following example:

1. Pick Model1/Branch1 and click on "Create Model/Branck Pair", this will generate a pair Model1-Branch1 as image below shows.
2. Pick Model1/Branch2 and click on "Create Model/Branck Pair", this will generate a pair Model1-Branch2 as image below shows.
3. Pick Model1/Branch1 and click on "Create Model/Branck Pair", nothing will happen since this pair was added on the (1) step and this is the right behavior to follow meaning **do not allow repeated pairs**

Now taking the example above you should have a table like this:

```
checkbox    Model1-Branch1
checkbox    Model1-Branch2
```

Following with the logic now:

1. Pick Model1/Branch1 and Model1/Branch2 pairs and from the Manufacturers table pick Manufacturer1 and click on "Create Model/Branck-Manufacturer Pair", this should generate something like this below:

   ```
   Mark to Delete |  Model/Branch    |   Manufacturer
   ----------------------------------------------------
   checkbox       |  Model1-Branch1  |   Manufacturer1
   checkbox       |  Model1-Branch2  |   Manufacturer1
   ```
2. Pick Model1/Branch1 and Model1/Branch2 pairs and from the Manufacturers table pick Manufacturer1 and Manufacturer2 and Manufacturer3 and click on "Create Model/Branck-Manufacturer Pair", this should generate something like this below:

   ```
   Mark to Delete |  Model/Branch    |   Manufacturer
   ----------------------------------------------------
   checkbox       |  Model1-Branch1  |   Manufacturer1
                  |                  |   Manufacturer2
                  |                  |   Manufacturer3
   ----------------------------------------------------
   checkbox       |  Model1-Branch2  |   Manufacturer1
                  |                  |   Manufacturer2
                  |                  |   Manufacturer3
   ```
3. Pick Model1/Branch1 and Model1/Branch2 pairs and from the Manufacturers table pick Manufacturer1 and click on "Create Model/Branck-Manufacturer Pair", nothing should happen since this pair was added on the (1) step and this is the right behavior to follow meaning **do not allow repeated pairs**

So, why the results from `#createM` on click event are not show in `#ModelBranchManufacturer`? Where I'm making something wrong in my code? I made [this](http://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/1bw3eL17/7/) Fiddle for testing purpose

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some hours of coffee and a lot of headaches I got the solution and it's working. Maybe this code is a bit different from the main on the post since I made some changes but the idea still:

```
function modelBranchManufacturerObject(config) {
        var instance = this;

        // initialize class vars
        instance.modelKey = config.modelKey;
        instance.branchKey = config.branchKey;
        instance.manufacturerCollection = [];
        instance.modelName = config.modelName || 'Sin nombre asignado';
        instance.branchName = config.branchName || 'Sin nombre asignado';

        instance.globalKey;

        // globalKey = modelKey + branchKey
        instance.getGlobalKey = function () {
            if (!instance.globalKey) {
                instance.globalKey = instance.modelKey + '-' + instance.branchKey;
            }

            return instance.globalKey;
        }
    }

    var modelBranchManufacturerCollection = {};

    function addNewRelationModelBranch(modelKey, branchKey, modelName, branchName) {
        var tempModelBranchManufacturerObjectInstance = new modelBranchManufacturerObject({
            modelKey: modelKey,
            branchKey: branchKey,
            modelName: modelName,
            branchName: branchName
        });

        var globalKey = tempModelBranchManufacturerObjectInstance.getGlobalKey();

        if (!modelBranchManufacturerCollection[globalKey]) {
            modelBranchManufacturerCollection[globalKey] = tempModelBranchManufacturerObjectInstance;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

        return tempModelBranchManufacturerObjectInstance;
    }

    function addNewRelationModelBranchManufacturer(globalKey, manufacturerArray) {
        var manufacturerCollection = modelBranchManufacturerObject.manufacturerCollection;

        if (modelBranchManufacturerCollection[globalKey]) {
            if (manufacturerCollection !== manufacturerArray) {
                modelBranchManufacturerCollection[globalKey].manufacturerKeyCollection = manufacturerArray;
                return modelBranchManufacturerCollection[globalKey];
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    $("#btnCrearParMarcaModelo").on("click", function () {
        var currModel = $("#modeloBody").find("input[type='radio']:checked").val(),
                currBranch = $("#marcaBody").find("input[type='radio']:checked").val(),
                currModelName = $("#modeloBody").find("input[type='radio']:checked").parent().next('td').text(),
                currBranchName = $("#marcaBody").find("input[type='radio']:checked").parent().next('td').text(),
                ModelBranchObject, tr;

        if (currModel && currBranch) {
            ModelBranchObject = addNewRelationModelBranch(currModel, currBranch, currModelName, currBranchName);
            if (ModelBranchObject) {
                tr = '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" value="' + ModelBranchObject.globalKey + '" /></td>';
                tr += '<td>' + ModelBranchObject.modelName + '-' + ModelBranchObject.branchName + '</td><td id="' + ModelBranchObject.globalKey + '"></td></tr>';
                $("#parMarcaModeloFabricanteBody").append(tr);
            }
        }

        $("#parMarcaModeloFabricante").show();
    });

    $("#btnAgregarSelFabricante").on("click", function () {
        console.log("d");
        var checkedModelBranch = $("#parMarcaModeloFabricanteBody").find("input[type='checkbox']:checked"),
                checkedManufacturers = $("#selFabricanteBody").find("input[type='checkbox']:checked"),
                manufacturerColl = [],
                modelBranchManufacturerCollection;

        var j = checkedManufacturers.length, item;
        while (j--) {
            item = checkedManufacturers[j];
            if (item.type && item.type == 'checkbox' && item.checked) {
                manufacturerColl.push({
                    id: item.value,
                    name: item.parentNode.nextSibling.innerHTML
                });
            }
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < checkedModelBranch.length; i++) {
            modelBranchManufacturerCollection = addNewRelationModelBranchManufacturer(checkedModelBranch[i].value, manufacturerColl);
            if (modelBranchManufacturerCollection) {
                //$("#parMarcaModeloFabricanteBody td#" + checkedModelBranch[i].value).siblings().attr("rowspan", modelBranchManufacturerCollection.manufacturerKeyCollection.length);

                for (var k = 0; k < modelBranchManufacturerCollection.manufacturerKeyCollection.length; k++) {
                    $("#parMarcaModeloFabricanteBody td#" + checkedModelBranch[i].value).append((modelBranchManufacturerCollection.manufacturerKeyCollection)[k].name + '<br/>');
                }
            }
        }
    });
```